# Error fulfilling a column when comparing with a lookup table in another schema

Tags: mysql, where-clause, lookup-tables

I have a problem trying to fulfill a column id 'like' when comparing the values with another ones in a different schema.

This is the code I'm using:

```
update oldb.incidencias set impact_id = 
    (select impact_id
    from
        newdb.impacts
    where
         olddb.incidencias.impacto = newdb.impacts.impact_type);
```

And this is the error I get:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'olddb.incidencias.impacto' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
update o
set o.impact_id = n.impact_id
from  oldb.incidencias o
inner join newdb.impacts n 
  on o.impacto = n.impact_type
```

Or

```
update oldb.incidencias o
inner join newdb.impacts n 
  on o.impacto = n.impact_type
set o.impact_id = n.impact_id
```